# Best way to extract all contents in a zip using Ruby

Tags: ruby, zip

I have a 200mb zip file, which I want to extract to a temporary folder for processing. I have experience with rubyzip library before. However it seems that extracting all files using it is a bit of pain [according to this blog post](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2008/10/02/ruby-unzipping-a-file-using-rubyzip/), needing to create directory before extracting individual files:

Is there an easier way to extract all things into a directory? It needs to work on both Mac OS X and Linux, but would be better if the solution is truly cross-platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux has a command line utility called `unzip` that will do it, IIRC.  If that utility is available on Mac OS then you can just call it from ruby using `system()` or back ticks.